# Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: java, maven, jar, intellij-idea, compilation

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to compile a project into a jar using the pom.xml. I've made some small changes to a plugin, and I'm wanting to compile it for use. However, when trying to compile it using "mvn install" in the directory with "pom.xml" in it, I get the error: http://puu.sh/6Hs2f/92c3a81adb.png

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuitespawn</groupId>
    <artifactId>BungeeSuiteSpawn</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>BungeeSuiteSpawn</name>

    <properties>
        <build.number>${BUILD_NUMBER}</build.number>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bukkit-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vault-repo</id>
            <url>http://ci.herocraftonline.com/plugin/repository/everything</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>md-5</id>
            <url>
                http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeSuiteTeleports/com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuiteteleports$BungeeSuiteTeleports/lastBuild/artifact/
            </url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuiteteleports</groupId>
            <artifactId>BungeeSuiteTeleports</artifactId>
            <version>0.50</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

GitHub project: https://github.com/Nentify/BungeeSuiteSpawn

Comment: why not just upload picture with stackoverflow image upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minecraftdimensions.bungeesuitespawn`artifact not exist on repository`http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/`.

You can download the jar frm the repository and using the system scope you can create the build.
`${basedir}` is the directory of your pom.

```
 <dependency>
        <artifactId>..</artifactId>
        <groupId>..</groupId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>0.5</version> 
        <systemPath>${basedir}/BungeeSuiteTeleports.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: But shouldn't exist on repo #3?

Comment: wht do you mean by repo #3

Comment: <repository>
            <id>md-5</id>
            <url>
                http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeSuiteTeleports/com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuiteteleports$BungeeSuiteTeleports/lastBuild/artifact/
            </url>
        </repository>

Comment: how you declare this 3 repo in setting.xml ?

Comment: Where's setting.xml? I only have pom.xml with the 3 repos in.

Comment: you are creating the build using mvn correct.mvn contain setting.xml which contain repo detail plz check it

Comment: settings.xml is empty, what should I put in it?

Comment: i m too not much knw abt it.plz you can have idea frm http://maven.apache.org/settings.html link or searching on google

Comment: Not sure what I need to put in it to fix the issue. Anyone else know?

Comment: sry my mistake @user3163221 u dnt need to update setting.xml.I m looking into the issue and let u knw

Comment: you was correct that jar exist in one of the repository i.e md-5 but when you open the pom.xml of that jar which is at http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeSuiteTeleports/com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuiteteleports$BungeeSuiteTeleports/lastBuild/artifact/com.minecraftdimensions.bungeesuiteteleports/BungeeSuiteTeleports/0.50/BungeeSuiteTeleports-0.50.pom you will found that pom having repository as http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public so it fails to load jar.You can do one thing download the jar and put in local repository

Comment: What would I put in my pom.xml file for this?

Comment: @user3163221  if it work thn select as correct answer